# Multiple SQL query within a table

Tags: sql

So I have an Incident table:

```
    incidentID | threatlevel | typeOfIncident | region 
    __________________________________________________
         1           5              H1N5         West
         2           5         Zombie Apocalyse  West
         3           5         Zombie Apocalyse  South
         4           5              H1N5         North
         5           5         Zombie Apocalyse  East
         6           3         Zombie Apocalyse  West
```

How do i retrieve the sum of threatlevel for each region based on the 2 different type of incidents?
I tried GROUP BY region, but it eliminates all the similar region.

How can i go about retrieving all these values in a single SQL statement:

For e.g.

total threatlevel of 0 for Zombie Apocalypse from the North region,

total threatlevel of 5 for Zombie Apocalypse from the South region,

total threatlevel of 5 for Zombie Apocalypse from the East region,

total threatlevel of 8 for Zombie Apocalypse from the West region,

total threatlevel of 5 for H1N5 from the North region,

total threatlevel of 0 for H1N5 from the Southregion

total threatlevel of 0 for H1N5 from the Eastregion

total threatlevel of 5 for H1N5 from the West region,

Return such that:
 0 AS ZombieNorth, 5 AS ZombieSouth, 5 AS ZombieEast, 8 ZombieWest,  5 AS      H1N5North, 0 AS H1N5South, 0 AS H1N5East, 5 H1N5West,

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: I removed the extraneous tags.  Please tag the question with the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 2):

In any databases, you can use two keys for the `GROUP BY`:

```
select typeOfIncident, region, sum(threatlevel) as total_threatlevel
from t
group by typeOfIncident, region;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT typeOfIncident, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN region = 'West' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS WestThreatLevel,
       SUM(CASE WHEN region = 'East' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS EastThreatLevel,
       SUM(CASE WHEN region = 'North' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS NorthThreatLevel,
       SUM(CASE WHEN region = 'South' THEN threatlevel ELSE 0 END) AS SouthThreatLevel
FROM mytable
GROUP BY typeOfIncident
```

The `SELECT` clause uses *conditional aggregation* in order to calculate the sum of `threatlevel` for each separate `region`.

Comment: @Janooying Can you update your question to include the expected result set for the sample data provided?

Answer (score 0):

You have the following in your question that confuses me :

> total threatlevel of 8 for Zombie Apocalypse from the West region
>
> ...
>
> total threatlevel of 5 for Zombie Apocalypse from the West region

Assuming that second one should have been

> total threatlevel of 5 for H1N5 from the West region

Then I think the answer is

```
SELECT 
 region
,typeOfIncident
,SUM(threatLevel)
FROM 
 <table>
GROUP BY
 region
,typeOfIncident
;
```